# Saving transparency settings in KML?

Tags: qgis, layers, kml

Is it possible to save a KML layer's style? My layer is set to 50 % opacity and I want to save that setting into the KML-file. The plugin qgistokml can´t yet do it, and only work with points.

Comment: check this plugin:qgis2google2

Comment: @Arun Unfortunaly it´s broken. Seems like it hasn´t been updated for 3 years...

Comment: You should contact the author to let him explain a bit more which data sources he regards as valid input formats.

Comment: Check. I´ll be back with more info when he replies....